# add password in a pdf file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, passwords

i just want to ask how can i add a password on a existing PDF file, i just created a pdf file using crystal reports and i kinda need to add some security features for the report. Thank you very much in advance.

lets say the file "c:\Folder1\sample.pdf" already exist. i have seen codes like the one below, but i don't know if it works because i don't know what to add in my reference to make it work

```
                    ' Define input and output files path.
                    Dim intputFilePath As String = Program.RootPath + "\\" + "1.pdf"
                    Dim outputFilePath As String = Program.RootPath + "\\" + "1_with_pw.pdf"
                    ' Set passwords for user and owner.
                    Dim userPassword As String = "you"
                    Dim ownerPassword As String = "me"
                    ' Create password setting.
                    Dim setting As PasswordSetting = New PasswordSetting(userPassword, ownerPassword)

                    ' Add password to plain PDF file and output a new file.
                    Dim errorCode As Integer = PDFDocument.AddPassword(intputFilePath, outputFilePath, setting)
                    If errorCode = 0 Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Success")
                    Else
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed")
                    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Dim WorkingFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
                    Dim InputFile As String = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "PSNOs.pdf")
                    Dim OutputFile As String = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "PSNOs_enc.pdf")
                    Using input As Stream = New FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
                        Using output As Stream = New FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                            Dim reader As New PdfReader(input)
                            PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, True, Nothing, "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS)
                        End Using
                    End Using
```

the word "PdfReader" have an error message but it doesn't ask to import something..